# Auth After Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I wish to authenticate the user after the request with my own middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate;

class AuthenticateAfter extends Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string[]  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

I extend `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` and modify the `handle` method to run as after middleware.

It's then declared in my kernel and on the correct route.

But I always get kicked back to the page I was previously on after logging in.

I want to control the page I go to, so before the middleware kicks in I do:

```
$request->session()->put('url.intended', 'my-test-url');
```

But it fails to redirect to this route.

How can I get it to redirect to a custom route?

Answer (score 0):

Try with: return redirect('view') or return redirect()->to('/route')

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

    return redirect('/your_page_path');    
}
```

Just for reference, here what I use to authenticate a user:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user() && auth()->user()->type != 'admin')
    {
        return redirect('/unauthorized');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```